# Why can't energy conservation nor momentum conservation be used to solve this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum, energy-conservation, friction

> A block of mass m is launched op an incline with speed $u$ on a rough incline. If it reaches the top find the minimum value of $u$. (slant height $l$)
> Ans- $u=\sqrt{2gl(\sin \theta+\mu \cos \theta)}$

Why am I not getting the same solution of the question using energy conservation (I get $u=\sqrt{2gl\sin\theta}$). If this incline would have been a frictionless incline then the answer would have been correct.
So can't you conserve energy or momentum to solve this? If not, why?

Comment: If your question is about energy and momentum conservation, I would recommend that you edit your question title to reflect that.  Questions whose titles are just cut-and-paste problem statements tend to get closed pretty quickly around here, even if the actual question being asked is an honest conceptual one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to use a conservation law, you have to define your system and look at the forces acting on it. In this case, your system is the block.

Energy is not conserved because there is a non-conservative force acting on the system, namely friction.

Momentum is not conserved because there is an external force acting on the system (three of them—gravity, friction, and the normal force.)

So the conditions for either conservation law to hold are not present, and we can’t use them to solve the problem.